# Can't find AWS Lightsail permissions policy for my IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I'm trying to set up Lightsail on AWS to run a Wordpress installation.

When I try to get in using my 'user' account, I get this error:

```
https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/error/access-denied

There might be a problem.
It looks like you aren't authorized.

If you're signed in as an IAM user, ask your administrator to create a permissions policy that grants access to Amazon Lightsail resources and related AWS services.
```

But when I log in with my admin user account, I can't see any Lightsail policies in the permissions policies lists.

[image]

Where can I enable the correct policy? Currently I can only set up my Lightsail server as the admin user, not with my user account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct, there is no Managed Policy for Amazon Lisghtsail access.

You will need to create your own **inline policy** to grant access.

To grant full permissions, use:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lightsail:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

For full instructions, see: [Managing access to Amazon Lightsail for an IAM user | Lightsail Documentation](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-managing-access-for-an-iam-user)